# palm api often returns nothing

Tags: python, palm-api

I'm using the palm api from python - and using either text_generation or chat - it does the same thing.  I send in a prompt like:

```
summarise this:
a bunch of text
```

and it works perfectly - but I want a summary of my *conversation*.   so if I send in this:

```
summarise this:
{ "role":"user", "content": "Something" },
{ "role":"assistant", "content" : "some response" },
...
```

100% of the time, it just returns nothing - and when I say that - if I do:

```py
     completion = palm.generate_text(
                model="models/text-bison-001",
                prompt=prompt,
                temperature=temperature,
                max_output_tokens=2000,
            )
```

completion.result is None,
completion.safety_feeback is empty,
completion.candidates is empty
and there doesn't appear to be any error field or something I can look at.

Temperature is a variable here because I made a loop to try it with ever increasing values - and it always just returns nothing.  I get exactly the same result if I use the palm.chat api.

so it's sort of a two part question:

1. Is there any way to get palm to summarise a conversation?
2. is there any way to troubleshoot why palm just returns nothing?

Comment: I think that you should send:

`{ "role":"user", "content": "Something" },{ "role":"assistant", "content" : "some response" },{ "role":"user", "content": "Summarize the conversation so far." },`

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Comment: the two questions are basically the same - ie either give me a solution to the problem, or a way to solve it myself.

I tried putting the summarize at the end as you suggest - it made no difference.